# Neo4j Windows Startup Error

Tags: neo4j

I've just installed Neo4j 3.1.1 on Windows.

When it finishes, I get the startup screen which has 'Status' of "Choose a graph database directory, then start the server".

The 'Database Location' displays the path "C:\Users\\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb".

It seems that whatever directory I chose, I get the same error message: 'Please choose a different folder.' but with a different value for 'Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement'; for example, '@3d5138f9'.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: If I leave the "Database Location" path set to 'C:\Users\\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb' and press the Start button I get the error 'Starting Neo4j failed: Multiple exceptions'.

Comment: Just tried it again, without changing anything, and I get a different error message:

Comment: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@2c7a9c05' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.

Comment: Can you post what the attached `cause exception` is?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run Neo4j as administrator, at least for each time you would like to change your default database location. I just had this problem myself, and I guess the issue is that Neo4j is trying to save the default database location to a file in the `Program Files` folder (which is somewhat against [the documentation on their site](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-define-my-graphdb-at-a-path-other-than-under-neo4j-home-for-windows/)).

The `Program Files` folder is by default protected by the Windows User Access Control (which is a good thing). So if you installed Neo4j to your `Program Files` folder (as is expected), and you do not run as administrator, Neo4j wouldn't have the necessary security permissions needed to save to the `Program Files` folder.

The culprit file is aptly named `.dblocation`, and is found in the `bin` folder of the Neo4j installation folder. If this file has been created, you can edit the file directly yourself by saving the folder path to your database to it. If that doesn't work, delete the file, and make sure you run Neo4j as administrator on the next run. It would first give that same error on startup, ignore it, and proceed to choose your database folder instead. Once you do this, Neo4j should save the folder path to your database to a newly created `.dblocation` file itself. After this is done, you shouldn't need to run as administrator anymore.

I think they need to change this behaviour in their next release, and instead stick to their documentation, or update it.